# SQL Server Extended Events module_start missing NestLevel info

Tags: sql-server, profiler, extended-events

Is there a way when tracing using Extended events in SQL Server to display Nested Level of nested procedure? Deprecated Profiler has a column named NestLevel for SP:Starting which can nicely describe the hierarchy of nested procedures. But I could not find the same column in Event Fields (nor Global Fields) for module_start event.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at either the tsql_stack or tsql_frame actions that you can add to any extended event? I think either should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nested level Event under sp_statement_starting and sp_statement_complete.